# Can I use a round metal electrical box for an exterior light fixture to be mounted in an insulated concrete form (ICF) wall?

Tags: electrical, exterior

Can I use a round metal electrical box for an exterior light fixture to be mounted in an insulated concrete form (ICF) wall?

Comment: Can't answer without more detail. If the box will be flush with the finished surface the answer is most likely yes, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: The box needs to be listed if in concrete. If you are cutting the foam out and anchoring to the cement, yes